# Javascript using Lodash, convert array to plain object, without keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
const arr = [{a:'1',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'9',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'3',b:'b',c:'c'}]

const g = _.toPlainObject(arr)
console.log(_.mapValues(g))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The Question is how do i get ride, of the index keys`0,1,2` in front of each object in the result, and have really plain objects based on a value from each object.
Intended result:

```
{
  "1": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  },
  "9": {
    "a": "9",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  },
  "3": {
    "a": "3",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your "Intended result" is not valid.

Comment: @crashmstr, you are right, i just realized that i posted the wrong snippets. am modifying it.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a) each object has only one key with a value that can be parsed to a number, and b) none of these values can be contained more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.mapKeys()` to get the keys from the object's values.

Note: since the values are numeric (integer strings), the object properties would be displayed in an ascending order.

```js
const arr = [{a:'1',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'9',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'3',b:'b',c:'c'}]

const result = _.mapKeys(_.toPlainObject(arr), o => o.a)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is iteration order guaranteed for long arrays?

Comment: Since ES6 iteration order of **objects** is guaranteed - standard string keys by the order of insertion, integer keys by an ascending numeric order.

Comment: In the original array, 9 is before 3, is not that changing the order?

Comment: When converting the keys to the numbers, the properties are reordering according to the rules I've written in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to remap the object. No library required.

I know this code looks cryptic if you're not familiar with reduce. I promise it's not as complicated as it may appear. Read up on how reduce works and you'll be fine. (And I'm not sure whether my explanatory comments in the code help or just make it even harder to read.)

```js
const arr = [{a:'1',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'9',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'3',b:'b',c:'c'}]

const result = arr.reduce(
  // called for each item in arr. merges the current item and returns the result.
  (acc, {a, ...other}) => ( // pull the 'a' value, collect remaining properties in 'other'
    {
      ...acc, // keep prior iterations
      [a]: { a, ...other } // set the value of 'a' as a key, whose value is this iteration's entry
    }),
    {} // start with an empty object
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid data structure and is against the rules of `objects` in javascript. An object or dictionary in python will always be shaped in a key and value pair such as `{ key: value }`

You can get the values of each key using `Object.values()`. This will return an array of objects containing all the values which you can use. But in general, your data structure is not correct.